# Tabulator.js: cellClick callback is not fired when clicking a checkbox

Tags: javascript, tabulator

I need to recalculate the table by calling `recal` after a row was selected by check box. If it is selected by clicking the row calling `recal` works. I copied the below code from plugin [site](http://tabulator.info/examples/4.9#selectable-tick)

```
  {formatter:"rowSelection", titleFormatter:"rowSelection", hozAlign:"center", headerSort:false, cellClick:function(e, cell){
    console.log("table ",table);
     // cell.getRow().toggleSelect();
    console.log("table ",table);        
    table.recalc();
  }},
```

but nothing gets executed. The checkbox gets checked and the row highlighted. You can try my [jsFiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/radek/tz6fk2qd/120/)

**UPDATE 1**
so it works if I click off the checkbox but I want the function to be triggered when the checkbox is clicked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**As the name suggest `cellClick` which should be called on cell element click there is another element which is considered cell and checkbox is contained inside cell that's why `cellClick` is not trigger when you click checkbox and triggered when click outside of checkbox**

1. Issue
   As Suggested by @EugeneOlisevich instead of listening to `cellClick`, Listening to `rowSelectionChanged` would be better option.

   Instead of using `table` to call `recalc` as `table` reference is not created until first load completes.

   Another way you can access `recalc` function is through `this`

```js
...
rowSelectionChanged: function(e, row) {
    this.recalc();
},
...
```

2. Issue
   When you click editable column if row is selected then it will deselect the row
   which can be solve by preventing `event` bubbling to parent through `cellClick` function.

```js
...
{
    title: "mn",
    field: "mn",
    editor: "number",
    cellEdited: function(cell) {
        aktualizuj_m(cell);
    },
    cellClick: function(e, cell) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
    },
},
...
```

3. Issue
   As `table` reference is not created on first load here i added condition to not run loop until `table` reference is `undefined`/`null`

```js
table && values.forEach(function(value, index) {
    var row = table.getRow(index + 1);
    if (row.isSelected() && value) {
      calc = calc + value;
    }
});
```

4. Issue
   If you change `mn` column input to 0 then sum is not updated
   which can be solved by updating condition.

```js
...
if (typeof mnozstvi == "number") {
    cell.getRow().update({
      cena_m: cena * mnozstvi
    });
}
...
```

**Note:** Negative range can be input in `mn` column

Here working [example](https://jsfiddle.net/jLk8s793/)

Comment: thank you for the explanation. You and Eugene helped me to solve my issue I was facing but the question is really why the cellClick function is not trigger if I click the checkbox. It works if I click bit outside the checkbox though.

Comment: @Radek as the name suggest `cellClick` which should be called on `cell` element click there is another element which is considered `cell` and checkbox is contained inside cell that's why `cellClick` is not trigger when you click checkbox

Comment: I thought it might be my misunderstanding. so is there any Tabulator function that is triggered when a checkbox is clicked?

Comment: @Radek there a function [selectableCheck](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.9/select#setup-eligible) it is used to test if row should be selected or not if that does not work for you can create [custom selection](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.9/edit#edit-custom).

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use another event handler instead of listening to direct cell click or row selection (or it depends on behaviour you want)

Here is the link to fiddle to check the solution:https://jsfiddle.net/02phqxz8/

```
...,
rowSelectionChanged:function(data, rows) {
    if(table) {
    table.recalc();
  }
},
...
```

**What was changed:**
Instead you can handle rowSelectionChanged event. Every time it is called, by clicking row, or clicking checkbox you can call recalculate for table. Just be sure to check teh table object by default, because the event is fired prior the constuctor return tha table itself.
Or as an option to avoid this additoinal check every time, you can subscribe to this event right after table is created.

Comment: very good. Perfect solution to my problem. And great explanation. Not sure why you get downvote? maybe because you did not answer the question? But you solved the problem. :-) let me wait for more answers.

Comment: by any chance, would you know answer to my other question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65765534/how-can-i-remove-hide-one-checkbox-when-using-formatterrowselection-in-tabul

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood the problem. It was not clear at first that the calculate should ONLY be called when clicked on checkbox. I has the solution, but it is a bit hacky. Will udpate in some minutes.

Comment: provided jsFiddle is just part of my whole solution. Actually I was using `rowClick` for the same purpose. I calculate sum only for clicked rows so your solution is just great for me. I am happy.

Comment: I've updated the solution in jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/k4fxa1h5/
But I believe it's shoudl be handled very carefully.
With your question about removing checkbox - i just can't imagine now the other way than you propose already.

Comment: actually this one works better. Try the original one by clicking the mn column in order to change amount. It looses the row selection.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `rowSelectionChanged`

```
rowSelectionChanged:function(data, rows) {
    if (updatedDataLength != data.length) {
       updatedDataLength = data.length;
       table.recalc();
    }
},
```

```
var updatedDataLength = 0;
```

You need to add a local variable that could check data changed because the first time the table rendered, it will also call `table.recalc()` that will cause a problem of rendering the initial table.
So I suggest using to check updated data length to keep it simple rather than comparing whole data.

---

Or you can just add a flag `var tableRendered = false;`.

```
rowSelectionChanged: function(data, rows) {
      if (!tableRendered) {
         tableRendered = true;
      } else {
         table.recalc();
      }
    },
```

Comment: @Radak, haha I wasted my time, because I didn't review the Eugene Olisevich 's answer because you didn't check it, so I thought it was a wrong answer.
After adding my answer, I just had a chance to review his answer and it's a perfect solution, but I'll not remove my answer because I also spent my time to answer you :)
Please check or vote up, so others like me won't waste their time. Cheers!