# How can I remove, hide one checkbox when using formatter:"rowSelection" in Tabulator.js?

Tags: javascript, tabulator

I am using

```
  {formatter:"rowSelection", titleFormatter:"rowSelection", hozAlign:"center", headerSort:false, cellClick:function(e, cell){
           table.recalc();
  }},
```

but I do not want the marked checkbox (see the picture) to be displayed. You can use [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/radek/ujhtk9ps/61/) to try out.

Is that possible using Tabulator functionality? If not then I  am thinking that I can remove it from DOM in `renderComplete` function.

[image]

**UPDATE1**
actually I do not want all checkboxes that are on the "parent" level.

[image]

Comment: i am not able to understand you question properly can you please elaborate it more.

Comment: I want to know if there is a way to get  rid of the checkbox. Only the one I highlighted. Using Tabulator's settings. Of course I can remove it outside Tabulator but it is kind of hacking and I want to avoid it if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create custom `formatter` for it

Here i have created custom `DOM` element and only returned from formatter function if some conditions are met otherwise returned `null` which cause it to render empty cell.

`Tabulator` use `selectRow` module for selection

In custom formatter i checked if user has enabled `selectable` option if yes then it will enable `selectRow` module, then tested if its row or table if its a row then checkbox will select/deselect row which i registerd in `tabulator` to let it know that use this checkbox component, if it is not a row then it would be table for that i registered checkbox to header selection which selects/deselects entire table.

```js
var do_not_show_checkbox_ids = [1];

var tableDataNested = [{
    id: 1,
    name: "BalanceOil",
    _children: [{
        id: 11,
        name: "BalanceOil+",
        cena: 31,
        mn: 1,
        cena_1: 159
      },
      {
        id: 12,
        name: "BalanceOil Aqua",
        cena: 41,
        mn: 1,
        cena_1: 159
      },
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "Xtend",
    cena: 23,
    mn: 1
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "Xtend",
    cena: 23,
    mn: 1
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "Xtend",
    cena: 23,
    mn: 1
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: "Zinobiotic",
    cena: 24,
    mn: 1
  }
];

var table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
  movableColumns: true,
  data: tableDataNested,
  dataTree: true,
  selectable: true,
  columns: [{
      title: "Name",
      field: "name",
      headerSort: false,
      width: 200
    },
    {
      title: "Cena",
      field: "cena",
      headerSort: false
    },
    {
      formatter: function(cell, formatterParams, onRendered) {
        const data = cell.getRow().getData();
        if (do_not_show_checkbox_ids.indexOf(data['id']) == -1) {
          var checkbox = document.createElement("input");

          checkbox.type = 'checkbox';

          if (this.table.modExists("selectRow", true)) {

            checkbox.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
              e.stopPropagation();
            });

            if (typeof cell.getRow == 'function') {
              var row = cell.getRow();
              if (row._getSelf().type == "row") {

                checkbox.addEventListener("change", (e) => {
                  row.toggleSelect();
                });

                checkbox.checked = row.isSelected && row.isSelected();
                this.table.modules.selectRow.registerRowSelectCheckbox(row, checkbox);
              } else {
                checkbox = "";
              }
            } else {
              checkbox.addEventListener("change", (e) => {
                if (this.table.modules.selectRow.selectedRows.length) {
                  this.table.deselectRow();
                } else {
                  this.table.selectRow(formatterParams.rowRange);
                }
              });
              this.table.modules.selectRow.registerHeaderSelectCheckbox(checkbox);
            }
          }
          return checkbox;
        }
        return null;
      },
      titleFormatter: "rowSelection",
      hozAlign: "center",
      headerSort: false,
      cellClick: function(e, cell) {
        this.recalc();
      }
    },
    {
      title: "mn",
      field: "mn",
      editor: "number",
      headerSort: false,
      cellEdited: function(cell) {
        updateSum(cell);
      }
    },
    {
      title: "Sum",
      field: "sum",
      headerSort: false
    }
  ],
  rowClick: function(e, row) {
    // console.log(table.getRows().length);
  },
  renderComplete: function(t) {
    this.getRows().forEach(function(value, index) {
      console.log(value.isSelected());
      var children = value.getTreeChildren();
      for (let j = 0; j < children.length; j++) {
        const name = children[j].getData().name;
      }
      children.forEach(function(value, index) {
        // console.log("cena");
        var cena = value.getData().cena; //price

        // console.log(cena);
        var mnozstvi = value.getData().mn; //amount
        value.update({
          sum: cena * mnozstvi
        });
      });
      updateSum(value.getCell("mn"));
    });
  },
  selectableCheck: function(row) {
    //row - row component
    return row.getData().cena > 0; //allow selection of rows where the age is greater than 18
  },
});

function updateSum(cell) {
  var cena = cell.getData().cena; //price
  var mnozstvi = cell.getValue(); //amount
  if (mnozstvi) {
    cell.getRow().update({
      sum: cena * mnozstvi
    });
  }
}
```

Here working [example](https://jsfiddle.net/3t0gdLx9/)

tabulator documentation links - [custom formatter](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.9/format#format-custom)

**Note:** For info about how `tabulator` formatters works internally check [here](https://github.com/olifolkerd/tabulator/blob/master/src/js/modules/format.js)

Comment: it is just great. I do not understand the solution, I have to go through it few times and hopefully I will get it ;-) One more question.. could you use ID instead of name and more importantly how would the solution look like if I want to exclude an array of IDs?

Comment: would you also know answer to my other question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65779531/bottomcalcformatterparams-does-not-work-in-tabulator-js

Comment: thank you so much for the explanation. It always helps me.

Comment: Your solution broke the functionality of the top checkbox in the menu. It would not "tick" the boxes.

Comment: @Radek I have fixed the issue please check

Comment: could you please remove `console.log` that outputs lots of data? I have troubles to run such jsFiddle. How do you deal with it? How can I stop jsFiddle from autorun? I do have it turned off.

Comment: Is it ok to ask what you had to do?

Comment: @Radek i in a habbit to see even more logs then that i have updated `jsfiddle` link and commented `console.log`.

Comment: so much of logs freezes the browser. I happens to me too then I have to wait, sometimes even for minutes to be able to use the browser again.

Comment: any chance you can explain what you did? The first solution was for me easier to understand.

Comment: @Radek i have added explanation in my answer if still any problem in explanation please let me know

Comment: would you know where to place some code I want to run when the upper checkbox in menu is clicked?

Comment: @Radek you can put it inside else block before `registerHeaderSelectCheckbox`, if you want it to run onchange then inside eventListener

Comment: I created a question for that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65818244/how-to-change-behaviour-of-header-checkbox-in-tabulator-js

Comment: I tried console.log() almost every where. None of them was fired.