# Tabulator Selection Eligibility

Tags: javascript, tabulator

I'm trying to use [selection eligibility](https://tabulator.info/docs/5.6/select#setup-formatting) on tabulator using a checkbox column, but I can't get it to work

Run the snippet below, some rows should be selectable and some not, but they all are.

```js
var tableDiv = document.querySelector("#tableDiv");

var tableData = [
    {id:1, name:"Oli Bob", age:"12", col:"red", dob:""},
    {id:2, name:"Mary May", age:"1", col:"blue", dob:"14/05/1982"},
    {id:3, name:"Christine Lobowski", age:"42", col:"green", dob:"22/05/1982"},
    {id:4, name:"Brendon Philips", age:"125", col:"orange", dob:"01/08/1980"},
    {id:5, name:"Margret Marmajuke", age:"16", col:"yellow", dob:"31/01/1999"},
];

var columnConfig = [ //Define Table Columns
    //my checkbox selection column
   {
        title: "",
        formatter: "rowSelection",
        titleFormatter: "rowSelection",
        hozAlign: "center",
        headerSort: false,
       
    },

    {title:"Name", field:"name", width:150},
    {title:"Age", field:"age", hozAlign:"left"},
    {title:"Favourite Color", field:"col"},
    {title:"Date Of Birth", field:"dob", sorter:"date", hozAlign:"center"},
];

var myTable = new Tabulator(tableDiv, {
    data: tableData,
    columns: columnConfig,
    selectableRowsCheck:function(row){
    //row - row component
    return row.getData().age > 18; //allow selection of rows where the age is greater than 18
}
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tabulator/5.5.2/css/tabulator.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tabulator/5.5.2/js/tabulator.min.js"></script>
<div id="tableDiv"></div>
```

Almost there...
Clicking the header checkbox selects all rows regardless of the condition

[image]

Follow up question here: [Selection eligibility not working with header checkbox on Tabulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78208186/selection-eligibility-not-working-with-header-checkbox-on-tabulator)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using version `5.5.2`, in this version, the prop to disable certain row's selection is called `selectableCheck`.

Bumping to `5.6.1` change the `selectableCheck` to the expected `selectableRowsCheck`.

To enable the selection of rows, you should enable that by passing `selectable: true` for `5.5` and `selectableRows: true` for `5.6`.

---

Based on [OP's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78200356/tabulator-selection-eligibility/78200434#comment137864554_78200434), these options allows you to toggle if the row is selectable by clicking it. Don't forget to enable the selection of rows in the first place, that seems to be missing in your code snippet.

Regarding removing the checkbox if the row isn't selectable, you can use a custom formatter, an example is found [in this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65765534/how-can-i-remove-hide-one-checkbox-when-using-formatterrowselection-in-tabul).

An other way is to use some CSS, there is a `tabulator-unselectable` class on the rows you're targeting, with some extra you can `display: none` the `input`.

```css
div.tabulator-unselectable > div:first-child > input {
    display: none;
}
```

---

- **`5.5.2`** Demo using **`selectable`** and **`selectableCheck`**

```js
var tableDiv = document.querySelector("#tableDiv");

var tableData = [
    {id:1, name:"Oli Bob", age:"12", col:"red", dob:""},
    {id:2, name:"Mary May", age:"1", col:"blue", dob:"14/05/1982"},
    {id:3, name:"Christine Lobowski", age:"42", col:"green", dob:"22/05/1982"},
    {id:4, name:"Brendon Philips", age:"125", col:"orange", dob:"01/08/1980"},
    {id:5, name:"Margret Marmajuke", age:"16", col:"yellow", dob:"31/01/1999"},
];

var columnConfig = [ //Define Table Columns
    //my checkbox selection column
   {
        title: "",
        formatter: "rowSelection",
        titleFormatter: "rowSelection",
        hozAlign: "center",
        headerSort: false,
       
    },

    {title:"Name", field:"name", width:150},
    {title:"Age", field:"age", hozAlign:"left"},
    {title:"Favourite Color", field:"col"},
    {title:"Date Of Birth", field:"dob", sorter:"date", hozAlign:"center"},
];

var myTable = new Tabulator(tableDiv, {
    data: tableData,
    columns: columnConfig,
    selectable:true,
    selectableCheck:function(row){
    //row - row component
    return row.getData().age > 18; //allow selection of rows where the age is greater than 18
}
});
```

```css
div.tabulator-unselectable > div:first-child > input {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tabulator/5.5.2/css/tabulator.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tabulator/5.5.2/js/tabulator.min.js"></script>
<div id="tableDiv"></div>
```

- **`5.6.1`** Demo using **`selectableRows`** and **`selectableRowsCheck`**

```js
var tableDiv = document.querySelector("#tableDiv");

var tableData = [
    {id:1, name:"Oli Bob", age:"12", col:"red", dob:""},
    {id:2, name:"Mary May", age:"1", col:"blue", dob:"14/05/1982"},
    {id:3, name:"Christine Lobowski", age:"42", col:"green", dob:"22/05/1982"},
    {id:4, name:"Brendon Philips", age:"125", col:"orange", dob:"01/08/1980"},
    {id:5, name:"Margret Marmajuke", age:"16", col:"yellow", dob:"31/01/1999"},
];

var columnConfig = [ //Define Table Columns
    //my checkbox selection column
   {
        title: "",
        formatter: "rowSelection",
        titleFormatter: "rowSelection",
        hozAlign: "center",
        headerSort: false,
       
    },

    {title:"Name", field:"name", width:150},
    {title:"Age", field:"age", hozAlign:"left"},
    {title:"Favourite Color", field:"col"},
    {title:"Date Of Birth", field:"dob", sorter:"date", hozAlign:"center"},
];

var myTable = new Tabulator(tableDiv, {
    data: tableData,
    columns: columnConfig,
    selectableRows: true,
    selectableRowsCheck:function(row){
          return row.getData().age > 18; //allow selection of rows where the age is greater than 18
      }
});
```

```css
div.tabulator-unselectable > div:first-child > input {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables@5.6.1/dist/css/tabulator.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables@5.6.1/dist/js/tabulator.min.js"></script>
<div id="tableDiv"></div>
```

Comment: But I can still see the checkbox, shouldn't the checkbox hide or be disabled?

Comment: I've update my answer with some more info, you are missing the initial setting to enable row selecting. Please run the code snippets. Hope it helps @TheOne.

Comment: Thank you, upvoted, I still feel it's an incomplete answer without hiding or disabling the checkboxes

Comment: Ow oke, well seems like those are not linked to each other, but [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65765534/how-can-i-remove-hide-one-checkbox-when-using-formatterrowselection-in-tabul) gives you an idea how to do that.

Comment: Added it to my asnwer, also a quick and easy CSS solution.

Comment: Nice, except, clicking the checkbox on the header selects all rows regardless of the condition (see edit)

Comment: You have to find that out yourself. There doesn't seem to be a supported route for this out of the box, so you'll need to make your own formatter with more options. But you keep adding requirements to the question, I'm not going to spend any  more time on this.

Comment: That's fine, I'm just looking for a complete answer, I appreciate your help.