# Selection eligibility not working with header checkbox on Tabulator

Tags: javascript, tabulator

I'm using [Selection Eligibility](https://tabulator.info/docs/5.6/select#setup-formatting) in Tabulator.

Run the snippet below, click the header checkbox and it selects all rows regardless of the eligibility condition. How can I fix this?

- **`5.6.1`** Demo using **`selectableRows`** and **`selectableRowsCheck`**

```js
var tableDiv = document.querySelector("#tableDiv");

var tableData = [
    {id:1, name:"Oli Bob", age:"12", col:"red", dob:""},
    {id:2, name:"Mary May", age:"1", col:"blue", dob:"14/05/1982"},
    {id:3, name:"Christine Lobowski", age:"42", col:"green", dob:"22/05/1982"},
    {id:4, name:"Brendon Philips", age:"125", col:"orange", dob:"01/08/1980"},
    {id:5, name:"Margret Marmajuke", age:"16", col:"yellow", dob:"31/01/1999"},
];

var columnConfig = [ //Define Table Columns
    //my checkbox selection column
   {
        title: "",
        formatter: "rowSelection",
        titleFormatter: "rowSelection",
        hozAlign: "center",
        headerSort: false,
       
    },

    {title:"Name", field:"name", width:150},
    {title:"Age", field:"age", hozAlign:"left"},
    {title:"Favourite Color", field:"col"},
    {title:"Date Of Birth", field:"dob", sorter:"date", hozAlign:"center"},
];

var myTable = new Tabulator(tableDiv, {
    data: tableData,
    columns: columnConfig,
    selectableRows: true,
    selectableRowsCheck:function(row){
          return row.getData().age > 18; //allow selection of rows where the age is greater than 18
      }
});
```

```css
div.tabulator-unselectable > div:first-child > input {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables@5.6.1/dist/css/tabulator.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables@5.6.1/dist/js/tabulator.min.js"></script>
<div id="tableDiv"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The workaround was to listen for the rowSelected event, and deselect the row after selection if it was not selectable.

```js
myTable.on("rowSelected",(row)=>{
if (row.getData().age <= 18) {
  row.deselect();
}

});
```

- **`5.6.1`** Demo using **`selectableRows`** and **`selectableRowsCheck`**

```js
var tableDiv = document.querySelector("#tableDiv");

var tableData = [
    {id:1, name:"Oli Bob", age:"12", col:"red", dob:""},
    {id:2, name:"Mary May", age:"1", col:"blue", dob:"14/05/1982"},
    {id:3, name:"Christine Lobowski", age:"42", col:"green", dob:"22/05/1982"},
    {id:4, name:"Brendon Philips", age:"125", col:"orange", dob:"01/08/1980"},
    {id:5, name:"Margret Marmajuke", age:"16", col:"yellow", dob:"31/01/1999"},
];

var columnConfig = [ //Define Table Columns
    //my checkbox selection column
   {
        title: "",
        formatter: "rowSelection",
        titleFormatter: "rowSelection",
        hozAlign: "center",
        headerSort: false,
       
    },

    {title:"Name", field:"name", width:150},
    {title:"Age", field:"age", hozAlign:"left"},
    {title:"Favourite Color", field:"col"},
    {title:"Date Of Birth", field:"dob", sorter:"date", hozAlign:"center"},
];

var myTable = new Tabulator(tableDiv, {
    data: tableData,
    columns: columnConfig,
    selectableRows: true,
    selectableRowsCheck:function(row){
          return row.getData().age > 18; //allow selection of rows where the age is greater than 18
      }
});

myTable.on("rowSelected",(row)=>{
if (row.getData().age <= 18) {
  row.deselect();
}

});
```

```css
div.tabulator-unselectable > div:first-child > input {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables@5.6.1/dist/css/tabulator.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables@5.6.1/dist/js/tabulator.min.js"></script>
<div id="tableDiv"></div>
```